# How to limit number of returned tags in git tag list

Tags: git, git-tag

How can I limit the tags which returned by running

```
git tag
```

into a specific number of tags? I have a very long list of tags and I only need to see what was the ten latest tags into my repository

Comment: List them all, then select the ten "latest", for which you will need define "latest".  Is the tag v2.9.1-rc2 later than v2.9.1?  Is v2.8.4 later than v2.9.0-rc0?  Does it depend on when the tag was added (the internal date of an annotated tag), or the author or committer date on the commit, or does it depend only on the name of the tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the tag list returned by `git tag` using `--sort` option. The details are available on the manual page : [git-tag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).

> The default sorting is lexicographic.
>
> Prefix - to sort in descending order of the value.

Then, you could use `head` command to filter on wanted number. If needed, you can `grep -v NOT_NEED_PATTERN` tag before getting the last 10 one.

**Example**

Assuming your tags increase numerically over version (e.g `1.0`, `1.1`, `2.0`, ...) , you can get 10 last tag with this command

```
git tag --sort=-refname |head -n 10
```

Answer (score 6):

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --count=10 --sort=-refname --format="%(refname:short)"
```